# Database connection refused while setting up Magento via terminal

Tags: database, magento, magento2.4

At the moment I am trying to setup Magento locally on my Mac, but I keep having trouble connecting to a database while trying to setup the project using my terminal. I have been following the Magento documentation and installed everything through Composer and set the file permissions to what they described.

When I want to run the bin/magento setup:install command with my credentials, I keep getting a "Connection Refused" error on my local database and also a remote database which my colleague set up.

Within the project I quickly checked if I could manually connect to my database using PDO and that worked perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? These are the credentials I am using:

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://magento.lcl \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento_lcl \
--db-user=root \
--db-password=test123 \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=EUR \
--timezone=Europe/Amsterdam \
--use-rewrites=1
```

The error I keep getting is:

***SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
In InstallCommand.php line 274:
Parameter validation failed***

I am also using MAMP PRO for my development.

Answer (score 0):

There can be issues with "db-host=localhost" try "db-host=127.0.0.1", in general the base_url should also rather be base-url=http://magento.lcl/ (with ending /).

If
mysql -u root -ptest123 -h 127.0.0.1 magento_lcl
successfully connects, you could try using debugger and see what happens in InstallCommand.php line 274.

Alternatively try installing via your browser
http://magento.lcl/setup, this will also have a look if your environment is set up correctly.

Generally I recommended you for local development just using DDEV (https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)